# how to get phalcon view render for wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: php, pdf, view, wkhtmltopdf, phalcon

I'm using [Phalcon Framework](https://phalconphp.com/) in my project. I have generated reports page and I want to convert it to pdf and download. After lots of googling I get [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf), but it's converting only html file to pdf. I have phtml file.
Can Phalcon render the view as html-strings or any other way I can convert?

Here is my code:

```
$pdf = new mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf(APP_PATH . '\\views\\views\\sales\\salesreports.phtml');
if (!$pdf->send()) {
   throw new Exception('Could not create PDF: ' . $pdf->getError());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phalcon rendering a template into variable as html string:

```
$view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View\Simple();
$view->setViewsDir(APP_PATH . '\app\views\views\sales\');
$optionalParams = [
    'var1' => 123,
    'var2' => 345,
];
// DO NOT put .phtml extension in the template name
$html = $view->render('salesreports', $optionalParams);
```

I'm, not familiar with `wkhtmlto\Pdf` library, but judging from the docs should look something like this:

```
use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;

$pdf = new Pdf;
$pdf->addPage($html);
$pdf->send();
```

Comment: is there problem rendering page if authentication required?

Comment: Just make sure you are rendering the page if user is authenticated? Before generating the `$view` check if user is logged.

Comment: $html variable comes empty

Comment: What is the purpose of second argument in render() ?

Comment: Make sure you are setting the correct `ViewsDir` path. Second parameter is optional for parameters (variables) you can use in your .phtml file. For example you want to personalize your message `Hello $userNames` etc...

Answer (score 1):

I think Mpdf would be great option.Its much easier to generate invoice.I used it in one of my project.It is very easy to install in your phalcon project.

Step 1: Go to project folder by cd.. command.

I wish You already have installed composer in your project.

Step 2:Run this command "composer require mpdf/mpdf" and wait until installation Done.

Step 3:Go to vendor fodder.You will see "mpdf" has been added.Ignore other folder.

Step 4:Go to your controller .Copy the following line.Coz u need to load External module in autoloader on run time. I hope your vendor folder is in the root directory.

Step 5:Copy  require_once **DIR** . '../../../vendor/autoload.php';
All set.

Step 6: Go to your function like public function pdfgenerateAction(){}

Step7:

```
public function pdfgenerateAction()
{
    $email = $this->request->getPost("email");

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();



    $mpdf->WriteHTML("<hr>");
     //Dont bother about this query.You can use Model as well.Just pass the array value to you foreach loop.
     $sheet = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
          ->columns("comment.comment, comment.username, comment.email, comment.postedat,item.name,item.photo,item.view,item.categoryid,item.id")
          ->From('comment')
          ->innerjoin('item', 'comment.productid = item.id')
          ->where("comment.email = '$email' ")
          ->getQuery()
          ->execute();        

    $table = "<table>
    <tr>
    <td >Given Name</td>
    <td >Email</td>
    <td >Bird Name</td>
    <td >Posted Time</td>
    <td >Your comment</td>
    <td >Total view by all </td>
    </tr>";
    foreach ($sheet as $row) {
        $table.= "<tr>
        <td >$row->username</td>
        <td >$row->email</td>
        <td >$row->name</td>
        <td >$row->postedat</td>
        <td >$row->comment</td>
        <td >$row->view</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    $table.= '</table>';

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($table);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML("<hr>");
    $mpdf->WriteHTML("<div style='display:block;position:fixed;bottom:0px;height:30px;width:100%' align='center'><strong>Your Footer of PDF</strong></div>");

    //$filename = $info->id;
    $filename = "Put your file name";
    //Crete folder inside your public folder
    $mpdf->Output("Foldername/$filename.pdf", 'F');




   $this->view->pick('pdf/response');
   // $this->flashSession->success("success :: PDF generated");
   // $this->response->redirect('user-home');



}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need something that can auto-generate HTML from given link and then convert it to pdf. So, I found an alternative for all this - **chrome headless**.